# iPhone: How to add Facebook Sign In Button?? (actual rendering)

Tags: iphone, facebook

I downloaded the Facebook API for iPhone and put it in my project. I am searching all over the internet but can't seem to find out how to actually display the sign up/log in with Facebook buttons in an iPhone App. All the tutorials seem to miss this aspect.. I mean, do I need to find the button images myself from the web and manually add them to the app as buttons? Looking for something like this:

```
FBSignInButton* b = [[FBSIgnInButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, heght)]
[self.view addToSubView:b];
```

that's it. Trivial right? How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you need to show the button to login to facebook just use

```
_loginDialog = [[FBLoginDialog alloc] init];    
[_loginDialog show];
```

when ever you think that the user should login to be given access to anything else in your app or something like to get the user info. before your app can do something with the users facebook account.

You can check the ray wanderlich tutorial on the same.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/77/how-to-post-on-facebook-with-your-iphone-app

I hope this is what you are looking for.